Custom CA with .NET 8 and GRPC without installing root CA
I've got a .NET application which communicates with an ASP.NET Core app via GRPC which I'm attempting to secure with mTLS using self generated certificates.
I've generated the following certificates:
- CustomCA
    - Client1 Cert
    - Client2 Cert
    - Server Cert

and configured both sides of the connection to use these certificates which is working perfectly IF I install my custom CA into the Windows Trusted Root Certification Authorities store.
Given these certificates will only ever be for app to app communication (i.e. there will never be a need for a browser or a user controlled application to communicate with the ASP.NET Core app), I'd like to avoid installing a new trusted CA if possible and configure a custom certificate store at both ends of my application.
I've managed to validate my certificates manually through a custom chain (i.e. caChain.Build(certificate) returns true
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
{
    var caCert = new X509Certificate2("./certs/ca-cert.pfx");
    var caChain = new X509Chain();
    caChain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add(caCert);
    caChain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
    caChain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.AllowUnknownCertificateAuthority;

    options.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(httpsOptions =>
    {
        httpsOptions.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.RequireCertificate;
        httpsOptions.ServerCertificate = new X509Certificate2("./certs/server.pfx");
        httpsOptions.ClientCertificateValidation = (certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
        {
            if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
            {
                return true;
            }

            bool isValid = caChain.Build(certificate);

            if (isValid)
            {
                return true;
            }

            Log.Error("Client certificate validation failed: {0}", sslPolicyErrors);
            return false;
        };
    });
});

However OnAuthenticationFailed is triggering in my certificate event callback.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCertificate(options =>
    {
        var caCert = new X509Certificate2("./certs/ca-cert.pfx");
        options.AllowedCertificateTypes = CertificateTypes.Chained;

        options.ValidateCertificateUse = true;
        options.ValidateValidityPeriod = true;
        options.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
        options.AdditionalChainCertificates = new X509Certificate2Collection(caCert);
        options.Events = new CertificateAuthenticationEvents
        {
            OnCertificateValidated = context =>
            {
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            },
            OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
            {
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            },
        };
    });

I've tried replacing my ClientCertificateValidation with (certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true; effectively disabling all checks but I still hit the OnAuthenticationFailed callback.
The one hint that I've found is if I inspect the chain within ClientCertificateValidation I can see that element 0 (the client certificate) has a Chain Element Status of 0 which I assume means it validated successfully where as element 1 (the CA) has a status of UntrustedRoot and a status information of

A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.

I assume this means the chain was validated but because nothing trusts my custom CA, the chain fails to validate
Is there a way I can load my custom CA into a trusted store specific to my application?

You are making a client/server connection and the certificate must be installed on both the client and server.  In you case the client and server are on the same machine.  So the certificate has to be installed on the machine so both the client and server has access.  The certificate must be installed in both the machine stores and the user stores areas.  The stores is in the user temporary file system.  So the account that is running the server app must have access to the certificate as well as the account that is running the client app.  The certificate is also loaded in the registry.

What do you mean by "The stores is in the user temporary file system"? My main goal is to avoid using any system stores

You can't.  Certificates have to be stored by client and server before they are used.

I was very close with my original code and after stepping through a bit of the validation process I've figured out a solution.
First up, my Kestrel setup
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
{
    var caCert = new X509Certificate2("./certs/ca-cert.pfx");
    var serverCert = new X509Certificate2("./certs/server.pfx");

    options.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(httpsOptions =>
    {
        httpsOptions.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.RequireCertificate;
        httpsOptions.ServerCertificate = serverCert;
        httpsOptions.ClientCertificateValidation = (certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
        {
            chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags |= X509VerificationFlags.AllowUnknownCertificateAuthority;
            if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return chain.Build(certificate);
        };
        httpsOptions.ServerCertificateChain = new X509Certificate2Collection
        {
            caCert,
            serverCert
        };

    });

});

Kestrel builds the correct certificate chain however because my CA is not "trusted" the chain was rejected. By adding the validation flag AllowUnknownCertificateAuthority before validating the chain, the custom CA is treated as trusted, allowing the remainder of the chain to validate. As far as I can see, there is no real security risk to changing this setting in my scenario.
On the authentication side, I needed to add a custom trust store and set the ChainTrustValidationMode to CustomRootTrust
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCertificate(options =>
    {
        var caCert = new X509Certificate2("./certs/ca-cert.pfx");
        options.AllowedCertificateTypes = CertificateTypes.Chained;
        options.CustomTrustStore = new X509Certificate2Collection(caCert);
        options.ChainTrustValidationMode = X509ChainTrustMode.CustomRootTrust;

        options.ValidateCertificateUse = true;
        options.ValidateValidityPeriod = true;
        options.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
        options.Events = new CertificateAuthenticationEvents
        {
            OnCertificateValidated = context =>
            {
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            },
            OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
            {
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            },
        };
    });

